# Hibernate documentation:@OrderBy - is it sorted in memory?

Tags: hibernate, sql-order-by, hql

In the documentation of [hibernate 4](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html) is following specified:

> 7.2.2.1. Lists
>
> Lists can be mapped in two different ways:
>
> as ordered lists, where the order is not materialized in the database
>
> as indexed lists, where the order is materialized in the database
>
> To order lists in memory, add @javax.persistence.OrderBy to your
> property. This annotation takes as parameter a list of comma separated
> properties (of the target entity) and orders the collection
> accordingly (eg firstname asc, age desc, weight asc nulls last), if
> the string is empty, the collection will be ordered by the primary key
> of the target entity.

I don't understand the note about that
*"To order lists in **memory**, add @javax.persistence.OrderBy to your property"*

Will be sorting procceed into memory of the **DBMS** using SQL orderby or into memory of my java application??

If i test it using just simple one to many relationship: (one user has more accounts) with such fragment

```
@javax.persistence.OrderBy("account-sum ASC, date DESC") // 
    private Set<Account> accounts= new HashSet<>();
```

The *order by* clause will be displayed in HQL Statement....

Is it possible to see the generated SQL on base of HQL statement?
Thanks a lot for your help:-)

Answer (score 0):

The sorting will be accomplished by adding an `order by` clause to the generated SQL so the database will handle the ordering.

Hibernate can be configured to show SQL by setting the `hibernate.show_sql` configuration property.

[See the hibernate documentation for configuring this property.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional)